# jQuery - Get value of textarea that contains HTML tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, richtext

### EDIT:

Using `$.text()` works as expected, the problem was originating from somewhere else. I'll not delete the question for future reference, in case someone runs into the - seemingly - same problem. Please also have a look at the accepted answer for solution.

---

I'm developing a rich text editor that reads contents from a `textarea` and creates an editable `div` using that content.

The problem is that I can't seem to get the HTML tags from the textarea, only the plain text.

**HTML code**

```
<textarea id="rtf-1">
    <h2>Big monster&nbsp;</h2><p>Kosova long crowing rooster test.</p>
</textarea>
```

**Javascript code**

```
var html = $('#rtf-1').html();
```

Can't figure out why, but `var html` is always 'Big monster Kosova long crowing rooster test.', the tags are assassinated somewhere in the process. The same happens when I try to use `$.text()` or `$.val()`.

I need `var html` to be `<h2>Big monster&nbsp;</h2><p>Kosova long crowing rooster test.</p>`. Any advice on how this could be done?

---

*Thanks for reading my answer. I'm not looking for alternative ways of initializing the rich text editor other than from the textarea contents (value) itself, and I'm certainly not looking for already existing RTF editors, like TinyMCE. If you can, please answer the question above.*

Comment: maybe use `.text()` instead? It will extract the text itself (tags and all), and then you can `.parseHTML()` afterward to get the HTML values again. something like `var html = $.parseHTML($('#rtf-1').text());`

Comment: @PlantTheIdea wouldn't that be something more like `var domNodes = $.parseHTML(...)`? `$.parseHTML` accepts an HTML string (as opposed to returning one).

Comment: Thank you for helping, as it turns out, the code works fine with `.text()`, but the problem was with associating `textarea` elements with their corresponding `div`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`textarea` elements don't actually hold HTML, so to get the equivalent of a string that represents the HTML, you would want to use `.text()`.  E.g.,

```
$('#render-to-me').html($('#rtf-1').text());
```

Here's a JSFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/44xjew92/

Comment: Thank you for answering, but as it turns out, it's a problem that originates from associating a given `textarea` with its corresponding `div`.

Comment: What do you mean by "associating" there?

Comment: The `div` created for rich-text editing gets assigned a generated but unique ID `rtf-editor-#`. The `data-rtf-editor` property of `textarea` equals the `id` of that new `div`. To be able to use the textarea in forms, an event handler `rtfchange` is also bound to the new `div`, one that updates the... well, now associated `textarea` contents. This association is where the problem originated from.